# Neo4j Server Closing for no Reason?

Tags: neo4j

I have a small database that was working fine just a day ago, but now, when I try to start it, the console claims that it succeeds in opening, but the web server hangs.

```
lsof -i | grep 7474
```

states that neo4j is listening to the port, and "close_wait"-ing, which I'm told means that the server side shut it down.

The only new error I get is that logback.groovy is missing, along with logback-test.xml, which is very odd, because I set logging to false in the neo4j config file.

Any idea what could be happening? Any one else encounter this problem?

Comment: This question might be better posed on http://serverfault.com/ (another stack exchange site), or possibly even http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no idea about those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `messages.log` for more detail about the shutdown reason.